# Setting an environment variable in Cygwin

Tags: shell, variables, cygwin, environment-variables

I have been trying to setup a environment variable in Cygwin using the command `export PRIMOSBASE=/directory/for/primosfiles`.

And when i check the variable using the command `echo $PRIMOSBASE` it shows the /directory/for/primosfiles. hopeful this means the environment variable is set.

But when i try to run a shell script(primos) for the /directory/for/primosfiles, it shows

```
./primos: line 8: /prilaunch.pl: No such file or directory
chmod: failed to get attributes of `step1.sh': No such file or directory
```

which means i have not set the PRIMOSBASE environment. could anyone please tell me where i am going wrong...

Thanks ...

Comment: Can you give us the contents of that shell script up to line 8? And how are you running that shell script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run

```
echo "export PRIMOSBASE=/directory/for/primosfiles" >> ~/.bashrc
```

to append the command to the end of your `.bashrc` file, so that the variable is set each time you use Cygwin. Then run

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

to make it take effect immediately.

**NOTE:** Make sure you use double brackets (`>>`) to append. It might be a good idea to make a backup of `.bashrc` just in case. If you're not comfortable with I/O redirection, an alternative is to edit `.bashrc` with an editor. I think `vim` is among the default tools in Cygwin.

Comment: @user1427429: You couldn't get it to work? What didn't work exactly?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue trying to get ANDROID_HOME to work in a Cygwin window. When I used the linux path separators, as follows
`ANDROID_HOME=/cygdrive/c/Users/User/AppData/Local/Android/sdk` my gradlew build script complained it couldn't find the sdk in `ANDROID_HOME`.

I eventually discovered that I had to set my environment variable in the Windows format, including Windows path separators `'\'`, as follows
`ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\sdk`

Note: the PATH and several other environment variables set in Windows are converted into Linux format. I hope this helps others who want/need to use Cygwin + Windows + essentially Windows programs that need environment variables.